# Cobordisms and compactness

Tags: differential-geometry, cobordism

Two compact $n$-manifolds $M_0, M_1$ are said to be *cobordant* if there is an $(n+1)$-dimensional compact manifold $M$ such that $\partial M = M_0 \sqcup M_1$.

What is the necessity of compactness here? From a naive perspective (i.e. mine) it seems as though we can just remove compactness from the definition, and just use two arbitrary $n$-manifolds $M_0, M_1$ instead.

Comment: Take any two $n$-manifolds $M_{0}$ and $M_{1}$. Then let's consider the (non-compact!) $n+1$-manifold $M_{0} \times [0,1) \cup M_{1} \times [0,1)$. I think this would be a non-compact cobordism from $M_{0}$ to $M_{1}$, so if we allow non-compact things then being cobordant is vacuous.

Comment: Is there any non-compact manifold $M$ such that $\partial M$ has two compact connected components? I'm just curious.

Comment: Peter, are you sayng that non-compactness implies that any two manifolds are cobordant?

Comment: @user477120 I'm saying that if we allow cobordisms to be non-compact, then any two manifolds are cobordant.

Comment: equivalently, every manifold is a boundary.

Comment: @See-WooLee: Yes of course: Take an open disc and remove two smaller open balls from it. The boundary of this manifold is two circles.